# Change language in custom middleware

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, internationalization

I would like to change language in my custom middleware. For some reason code below doesn't work.

```
class LanguageMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        print('set language to spanish...')
        translation.activate("es")
        request.LANGUAGE_CODE = "es"
        response = self.get_response(request)
        translation.deactivate()

        return response
```

settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ("en", "English"),
    ("es", "Spanish"),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),)
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"
```

if I change LANGUAGE_CODE is settings to "es" I get spanish API responses but I would like to be able to change it programmatically in my middleware.

Comment: Hmm, try removing that `translation.deactivate()` the template probably isn't rendered yet when you're calling that (Rendering the template is often handled at the end of the middleware chain)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def set_lang_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        translation.activate("es")
        response = get_response(request)

        return response

    return middleware
```

Do not forget to add your middleware in settings.MIDDLEWARE.